# post not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

this is my jscript code:
when i run it i get no response and firefox webconsole is showing ok

```
dataS = friendMediaArray; // array?
var jsonS = JSON.stringify(dataS);
$(function() { 
   $("#xbut").click(function() { 
      var data = {}; 
      data.dataArray = friendMediaArray; // I'm setting it as a property here 

      var jsonS = JSON.stringify(data); 
      jQuery.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          data: {type: "stream", namef: jsonS }, 
          url: 'catch.php', 



        success: function (msg) 
                { alert("OK");alert(data); console.log(data); },
        error: function (err)
        { alert(err.responseText)}
    });}); });
```

catch.php

```
<?php 
if($_GET['type']=='stream'){ 
     $obj = json_decode($_GET['namef']); 
   for($i=0;$obj[$i];$i++){ 
    echo $obj[$i]->{'namef'}." "; 
    } 
} 

json_decode($_GET['namef']); 

?>
```

i get undefined even with var_dump($_POST)
it seems like ther's nothing send

GRT robert

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below this question's tags to add more information to your question, rather than starting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using type: "GET", try:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataString = friendMediaArray; // array?
```

If your data is an array, you really should not name it something with "string"!

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
```

Now, your `jsonString` is a real string, and

```
jsonString[field.name] = field.value;
```

will result in *nothing*. You can't set properties of primitive string values. Instead, you will need to set them as properties of object, which you then can serialize:

```
$(function() {
   $("#xbut").click(function() {
      var data = {};
      data.dataArray = friendMediaArray; // I'm setting it as a property here
      $.each($(':input').serializeArray(), function(i,field){
           data[field.name] = field.value; 
      });
      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: {type: "stream", namef: jsonString },
          ...
      });
   });
});
```

Also note that when you send your data with `GET` as url parameters, `$_POST` will obviously be empty. Yet, `json_decode($_GET['namef']);` should give you the object you wanted.

Comment: ok it is a test code so all i want is to get my vars with php,i get a ok response but when i alert it to the screen it say's [object Object]

Comment: Your success function alerts a "data" variable from somewhere (which in case of my code is the object you just sent), not the "msg" it receives from the server!!!

Comment: ok i got my response it's like this:  array(2) {["type"]=>string(6) "stream" ["namef"]=>string(1028) "{"album":[{"albumid":"00000",etc  now how do i echo for example the albumid to the screen?

Comment: You have successfully parsed the received JSON string into your $obj PHP variable. Just access its properties!

Comment: ok i sorry for the stupidness but i try this but i get all of my data echo $obj->namef['mediaid'];

Comment: Sorry, I'm no PHP expert. Just try to inspect it using var_dump($obj)

Comment: ok sorry for my new post,

 I only get an empty messagebox, grt robert